# Figure or literature directory in "Pages", ist it possible?

Tags: ios, macos

I hope, that it is allowed here to ask such a question, if not just write me a comment and i will delete it.

So, I am trying to write a work in Pages (I know LaTeX is so much better, but I don't have the time to learn and write with LaTeX). I should write at the End "literature and Figure directory" so any idea  (if it is possible) ?
thanks
Josef

Comment: XPages is a Web development platform based on IBM Notes/Domino. You are looking for a word processor. I don't think XPages is the right tool for that use case. I'll delete the tag "XPages".